# how to get CurrentItem.duration without getting nan

Tags: swift, uiview, avplayer

I was following [A simple iOS view to play video](https://medium.com/@rodrigo_freitas/a-simple-ios-view-to-play-video-b7ee05f9ce6a) that helps you to display an `AVPlayer` in a `UIView`. It was very helpful, but unfortunately in the VideoView (custom created) it didn't include `currentItem?.duration`
So, I tried adding it by myself this way:

```
   func getCurrentItemDuration() -> Double
    {
        let duration = player?.currentItem?.duration
        let durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration!)
        return durationSeconds
    }
```

But when I tried to print it in my `UIViewController`, I got: Nan

```
class VideoView: UIView {
    
    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
    var player: AVPlayer?
    var isLoop: Bool = false
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)    
    }
    
    func configure(url: String) {
        if let videoURL = URL(string: url) {
            
     
            player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
            playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
            playerLayer?.frame = bounds
            playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resize

            if let playerLayer = self.playerLayer {
                layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            }
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachTheEndOfTheVideo(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem)
        }
    }
    
    func play() {
        if player?.timeControlStatus != AVPlayer.TimeControlStatus.playing {
            player?.play()
        }
    }
    
    func pause() {
        player?.pause()
    }
    
    func stop() {
        player?.pause()
        player?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
    }

     func getCurrentItemDuration() -> Double
    {
        let duration = player?.currentItem?.duration
        let durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration!)
        return durationSeconds
    }
    @objc func reachTheEndOfTheVideo(_ notification: Notification) {
        if isLoop {
            player?.pause()
            player?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
            player?.play()
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to fix this error so if anyone is familiar with this error please guide me to fix it. :)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you want to get he duration of the asset. So, try using :

```
CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentItem!.asset.duration)
```

It'll give you the duration of the current playing item in seconds.